# Python import Ms_graph ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, azure, onedrive, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to use the MS_graph python module to download files from onedrive.
I tried using the pip install msal command. But when you run the code, this error returns:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/spado/Desktop/ad.py", line 3, in 
from ms_graph import generate_access_token, GRAPH_API_ENDPOINT
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ms_graph*'

I accept any suggestions, even to use other code.

**The code i used:
**

```
import os
import requests
from ms_graph import generate_access_token, GRAPH_API_ENDPOINT

APP_ID = '<App ID>'
SCOPES = ['Files.Read']
save_location = os.getcwd()

file_ids = ['Folder Id1', 'Folder Id2']

access_token = generate_access_token(APP_ID, scopes=SCOPES)
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token['access_token']
}

# Step 1. get the file name
for file_id in file_ids:
    response_file_info = requests.get(
        GRAPH_API_ENDPOINT + f'/me/drive/items/{file_id}',
        headers=headers,
        params={'select': 'name'}
    )
    file_name = response_file_info.json().get('name')

    # Step 2. downloading OneDrive file
    response_file_content = requests.get(GRAPH_API_ENDPOINT + f'/me/drive/items/{file_id}/content', headers=headers)
    with open(os.path.join(save_location, file_name), 'wb') as _f:
        _f.write(response_file_content.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is no module named `ms_graph` or  `generate_access_token, GRAPH_API_ENDPOINT` libraries. You need to install `msgraph.core`. The following image indicates the classes present in this library `msgraph.core` after importing it.

[image]

However, I see you are trying to retrieve access token. So, one way to achieve this requirement is to use `msal`. Below is the complete code that was working for me.

```
import webbrowser
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication, PublicClientApplication

client_secret = '<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>'
client_id = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>'

SCOPES = ['User.Read']
client = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id=client, client_credential=client_secret)
authorization_url = client.get_authorization_request_url(SCOPES,redirect_uri='<YOUR_REDIRECT_URL>') 
webbrowser.open(authorization_url)

authorization_code = '<AUTHORIZATION_CODE>'
access_token = client.acquire_token_by_authorization_code (code=authorization_code, scopes=SCOPES,redirect_uri='<YOUR_REDIRECT_URL>')
access_token_id = access_token['access_token']
print(access_token_id)
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Hello! it returns me this: KeyError: 'access_token'

Comment: @DanieleSpadola Can you tell which method you have followed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the python package into your environment?

python3 -m pip install msgraph-core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=2

Comment: Used that command in cmd but nothing is happening